# Action Mode and accessibility

Tags: android, android-actionmode, accessibility

I currently have an activity with a toolbar.

The toolbar has some text and menu options. Selecting a menu option will enable *ActionMode*

Everything works well as I'm using :

`<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`

The only problem is that when in talkback mode, it still sees the toolbar  and it's title beneath as well as menu options so it voices these options to the user.

Hiding the toolbar is an option but is quite hacky.

Has anyone resolved an issue like this before?